# ImageView from URL Not wrapping content with custom height

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an image loading from a url using Glide, with the image I'm getting the image height. WHen I set the height, and width to match parent, the height is too high and there is empty space on bottom and top of image. The height is in pixels

This is how I'm setting height:

```
if (height != 0) {
            height = convertPixelsToDp(height, mContext);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

XML:

```
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/listphoto"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#dddddd"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />
```

I tried experimenting with adjustViewBounds and scaleType but nothing is working. It's not wrapping the top and bottom. How can I make this work?
I've been working on this all night

UPDATE:

```
 public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        return dp;
    }
```

Comment: This is probably because the height you're setting to your ImageView is larger than the actual height of your image. That's is why you are getting spaces on top and the bottom of the Image (fitCenter, remember?). Try figuring out what the height should be (with pxToDp(...)).

Comment: I logged the height, and it's same as it shows on the camera resolution settings, and I dont use px to do, but I forgot to delete that line

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You shouldn't be using the height of the Image (in pixels). Rather try to convert it to the size the device needs (different screen sizes have different DPIs). Also, it will be better if you add pxToDp() method to your question.

Comment: Oh I see, how would I convert ?

Comment: this will help: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @NileshSingh added px to dp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131377/discussion-between-nilesh-singh-and-franklinexpress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So, the answer is very simple. We just need to change the height of the ImageView with respect to the width of the image and the width of the screen. Doing this will set the image properly in the ImageView:

```
private float getHeight(float height, float width) {
    Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return (height * size.x / width);
}
```

If your ImageView has some margin or padding set to it, use this instead:

```
private float getHeight(float height, float width, int containerHeight) {
    return (height * containerHeight / width);
}
```

Then finally,

```
if (height != 0) {
        height = (int) getHeight(height, width);
        //or if has some margin or padding
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height;
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Or if has padding or margin:

```
if (height != 0) {
        height = (int) getHeight(height,  width, viewHolder.listphoto.getMeasuredWidth());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height;
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**Note: It will be a better if you go with the second one. It will ensure that even when you apply some margin/padding to your ImageView, the image sets properly in the ImageView ignoring the padding/margin.**

Comment: new Point is not being assigned anything, let me try, also I don't have the width but maybe I can assign that on the backend

Comment: so I have to get the width? What did you pass for width?

Comment: Yes you need to have the width of the image as well. Pass both the height and width of an example image and check the code

Comment: I'm using my adapter for Fragments and another activity, in the activity it says context can't be cast to Activity in the getHeight method

Comment: Yes, it does for any screen size because the imageview will adapt according to the image height and width

Comment: That was a typo. That was meant to be width. Just pass the width of your image and you're done.

Comment: I used ```WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();```

Answer (score 0):

add these attributes

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:cropToPadding="false"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

I think these two property will resolve the problem and please remove

```
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Change width to

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I want width to be edge to edge full width

Comment: then try with that but I think this problem coming due to image aspect ratio. Please once try with other options which I have mention ..

Answer (score 0):

```html
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This will work for you without giving scaleType.